# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pgService' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web-config, payment-gateway, configuration-files

I am working on payment gateway integration in which i am stuck at the a point. i am getting the error. I have tried all possible solutions but unable to proceed. Help me to identify the solutions.
I have servlet-context.xml in which i am importing my pg-context.xml by

> `<beans:import resource="classpath:pg-context.xml" />`

---

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pgService' defined in class path resource [pg-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.majesco.dcf.pg.service.PGService]: Specified class is an interface
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1021)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)

    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.majesco.dcf.pg.service.PGService]: Specified class is an interface
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
    ... 31 more

SEVERE: Servlet [appServlet] in web application [/ABHI] threw load() exception
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.majesco.dcf.pg.service.PGService]: Specified class is an interface
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1021)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
```

My pg-context.xml:

```
<!--context:component-scan base-package="com.majesco.dcf"/ 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.majesco.dcf.app.*" />

    <beans:bean id="pgService" class="com.majesco.dcf.pg.service.PGService" />-->

    <beans:bean id="pgService" class="com.majesco.dcf.pg.service.PGService" >
        <beans:property name="pgService" ref="PGService" /> 
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManagerPG" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourcePG" />
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryPG" />
        <beans:property name="hibernateManagedSession" value="false"/>
        <!-- <beans:qualifier value="pg"/> --> 
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="pgdbService" class="com.majesco.dcf.pg.service.PGDBService" >
        <beans:property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManagerPG" /> 
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSourcePG"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.pg_username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.pg_password}" />

    <beans:bean id="sessionFactoryPG"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourcePG" />
            <beans:property name="configLocation">
                <beans:value>classpath:pg.cfg.xml</beans:value>
            </beans:property>
            <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
                <beans:props>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</beans:prop>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${jdbc.pg_schema}</beans:prop>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${jdbc.hbm2ddl.auto}</beans:prop>
                </beans:props>
            </beans:property>
      </beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In this file pg-context.xml , you define like below

<beans:bean id="pgService" class="com.majesco.dcf.pg.service.PGService" >
        <beans:property name="pgService" ref="PGService" /> 
    </beans:bean>

But where you are getting **ref="PGService"**? Is there any bean you define with name "PGService"?
```